# GeoServer - render transformation reprojection issue

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, sld

I'm visualizing a NetCDF file with the NetCDF plugin and using `ras:contour` rendering transformation to display the isolines. The raster data and contours look correct when checking the layer in the original projection (NetCDF file is 4326). However I need to display the data in Web-Mercator and if I view the layer in 3857 the raster data itself looks correct but the contour lines are pixelated and follow the path of raster edges. Is this expected behavior or am I missing something to make this work?

Here's my SLD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld">
  <UserLayer>
    <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
      <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
    </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>sst_style</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
            <sld:ChannelSelection>
              <sld:GrayChannel>
                <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
              </sld:GrayChannel>
            </sld:ChannelSelection>
            <sld:ColorMap type="ramp">
              <sld:ColorMapEntry label="14" quantity="14" color="#2b83ba"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry label="15" quantity="15" color="#80bfac"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry label="16" quantity="16" color="#c7e9ad"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry label="17" quantity="17" color="#ffffbf"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry label="18" quantity="18" color="#fec980"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry label="19" quantity="19" color="#f17c4a"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry label="20" quantity="20" color="#d7191c"/>
            </sld:ColorMap>
          </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>levels</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>14</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>15</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>17</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>19</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>smooth</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        <sld:Rule>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>

            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
            </Font>

            <LabelPlacement>
              <LinePlacement>
              </LinePlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.85</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>

            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>

            <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="repeat">200</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="group">no</VendorOption>

          </TextSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </UserLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

This is how it looks in 4326:
[image: contours_4326]

Same area in 3857:
[image: contours_3857]

Comment: how are you doing the reprojection? can you add the request URLs

Comment: using leaflet as client, the request is`https://<host>/geoserver/sst/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=sst&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.3.0&time=2021-08-11T00%3A00%3A00.000Z&width=256&height=256&crs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2543824.301330666,8179373.522740141,2582960.059812676,8218509.281222154`

Answer (score 0):

In the layer settings, under publishing tab, try to change the "Default Interpolation Method" from "Nearest neighbour" to "Bilinear". That fixed the issue in my case.

[image]